# Oracle sql scripting. Querying. List the locations the company has employees located at

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hey I am struggling with a question, I am a beginner at database management. I have the following database, and I want to make this query:  [List the locations the company has employees located at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9mk.gif) and how many employees are at each location ordered by the location with the most employees in descending
Anybody help please!

this is the database

Comment: Please provide some of your  current code and some sample data.

Comment: SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM LOCATIONS;
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME
FROM COUNTRIES JOIN LOCATIONS USING (COUNTRY_ID) JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING (LOCATION_ID) 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEES 
  GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID 
  HAVING COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)=1)
GROUP BY COUNTRY_NAME;

Comment: This is my current work, it lists the locations the company has employees at, but I also need to list how many employees are at each location.

Comment: Kindly share sample data..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this gets what you're looking for.

```
Select l.location_id, c.country_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count
From locations l 
left join countries c ON c.country_id = l.country_id
left join departments d ON l.location_id = d.location_id
left join employees e ON e.manager_id = d.manager_id
GROUP BY l.location_id, c.country_name
ORDER BY employee_count DESC;
```

Comment: The result should list all of the locations that the company has employees at. This is only listing 5 locations for some reason.

Comment: 23, but many of them will have 0 employees from. But the result should list them!

Comment: Swapped out the inner join for a left join. The inner join was essentially eliminating the locations with no employees.

Comment: NICE. Can I see you script please?

Comment: oh nevermind, i see it. Thank you so much for your time!